# How to run an if else statement in Scala in Databricks streaming

Tags: scala, streaming, databricks

I am new both to Scala and to Databricks streaming. I am reading streamed events into a dataframe and I want to use an if-else statement to trigger a different notebook based on whether the dataframe is empty or not. The simple code below (and variations of it)

```
if(finalDF.isEmpty){ 
  print("0")
}
else{
  print("1")
}
```

persistently results in the following error

```
AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
eventhubs
```

How can I incorporate writeStream.start() into the above code? Or, how can I evaluate the dataframe content and based on that, take one or another action, given that the dataframe is populated by streaming events into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code and it works as a way to introduce an if-else and decide actions based on event contents.

```
df.writeStream.foreachBatch((df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, batchID: Long) => myfunc(df)).start()

def myfunc(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame){
    val test1= df.filter($"col" === "test1")
    val test2= df.filter($"col" === "test2")
    if(test1.count()>0){ 
        dbutils.notebook.run("some_notebook", 60)
    }
    if(test2.count()>0){
        dbutils.notebook.run("another_notebook", 60)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The streaming DF couldn't be empty or not by design - stream is infinite, and if you don't have data there right now, then you can get something new in next second. So your code won't work.

You can use [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) to process "current" snapshot of data with which you can work as with "normal", non-streaming dataframe, but then you **may not be able** to trigger the notebook from inside it, so code for both conditions should be inside the same function, not in different notebooks.

Comment: Hi @alex-ott, I added an update to the question above with a possible solution to call two different notebooks based on values from foreachBatch - wouldn't that then contradict what you said that you can't call different notebooks?

Comment: Ok, theoretically it may work (I updated the answer)... But I'm not 100% sure that this is the best practice